# Calculating the volume of $(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2 \le \sin^2(z) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, cylindrical-coordinates

I am trying to calculate the volume of $(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2 \le \sin^2(z) $ and $0 \le z \le \pi $. I am having trouble parameterising the equation and setting the bounds for the parameters. I think the $-z$ in the equation is just rescaling the object so it does not affect the volume. I have set the volume integral as $$ \pi \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2(z) dz$$ and found the volume as $\frac{\pi^2}{2} $. Is this the correct answer or is my calculation wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe your answer is correct. If you set $(u,v,w)=(x-z,y-z,z)$ then the volume becomes $$\iiint_{u^2+v^2\leq \sin^2(w) \\ 0\leq w \leq \pi}\Bigg|\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)}\Bigg|\mathrm{d}V$$ which turns out to be an iterated integral that represents the volume of the solid generated by rotating $$u=\sin(w),v=0,0\leq w \leq \pi$$ around the $w-$axis (in the $uvw-$plane)

Comment: It's a shift not a rescaling... for fixed $z$ you can replace $(x - z)^2 + (y - z)^2$ by $x^2 + y^2$ in the $xy$ integral since doing that just replaces a disk with a different disk of the same area. You end out with the expression you have there.